# Python 3 install error. This file does not have a program associated

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, installation

I have encountered an error while try to run a python 3.6.4 script after upgrading from 2.7.

I had initial installed both python 2.7 and 3.6 but them deleted 2.7 because I had no use for it and i am not getting this error.

I have tried:
Reinstalling python 3.6.4
changing the install location of said install
Repairing the python 3.6 install

Error:
[image: The error in question]

Comment: How do you run the script? By double-click?

Comment: Is the path for Python 3.6 set?

Comment: the path for 3.6 has been set

Comment: The script is run via the terminal

Comment: If you want to reply to someone pinging (@Rallo) sends a message to their inbox.  This is useful because you don't have to wait for them to have a look at  a question again

Comment: When you run it in the terminal, do you call it like this: `python Evosim.py`?

Comment: Ah sorry - just now I see that you included the terminal in the screenshot. It seems that you try to run the script by entering `Evosim.py` only.

Answer (score 0):

A Python script by itself is not an executable program. So if you want to run the script `Evosim.py` by just entering `Evosim.py` in the command line, the `.py` file ending needs to be associated with the Python interpreter. It seems that currently in your system this is not the case.

There are two ways to deal with your situation:

1. Start your script by entering `python Evosim.py` instead of only `Evosim.py` in the command line.
2. Fix the broken association of the `.py` file ending with the Python interpreter. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072837/python-is-not-opening-py-files) migth help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1

Go to your `registry` by searching `regedit`.
Open category `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Select `.py`. If `.py` don't exists then make it by yourself.
Double click the `Default`. It will make a popup. Change its value to **`Python.IDLE`** and click `OK`. Make a new `String key` in `.py` naming `Content Type` with value `text/plain`.

## Solution #2

If the above method don't works then just go ahead and reinstall your python (**also uninstall `Python Launcher`**). Your modules and files will be at their place.

You can now open `.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

Running command prompt as an administrator resolved my issue, and able to execute my python script

Answer (score 0):

1). Right click any python file

2). Click `Open with` then `Choose another app`

[image]

3). Click on `More apps` then `Look for another app on this PC`. It should open up file explorer

4). Select `python.exe` wherever it is located.

A sample path is `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe` for a user installation. A way to check this path is by typing `where python` into cmd; it will list all installations of Python.

[image]

Now the `python.exe` you chose is associated with all `.py` files and typing `file.py` should not give an error.